# I get HTTP 400 when using oauth post request

Tags: android, oauth

I am trying to use oauth for an application i am writing for android. I am getting so far that a proper authorization code is returned to my application. Now Í need to make a post request with that to get the access/refresh token. To do that I have to following code:

```
class post_get_access_token extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

private Exception exception;

protected String doInBackground(String... code) {
    try {
        String url = "https://login.eveonline.com/oauth/token";
        String charset = "UTF-8";

        String grant_type = "authorization_code";
        String enc_auth = Base64.encodeToString("9d7dcbb0380f450ea0d2b435b60f4c15:ssEAFgv5PfEs29bluxs9N3milKgC7j6saILCtMPw".getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);


        String query = null;
        try {
            query = String.format("grant_type=%s&code=%s",
                    URLEncoder.encode(grant_type, charset),
                    URLEncoder.encode(code[0], charset));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("eve_token_query",query);

        URLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        connection.setDoOutput(true); // Triggers POST.
        //connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
        connection.setRequestProperty( "Authorization", enc_auth);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=" + charset);

        try (OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream()) {
            output.write(query.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> header : connection.getHeaderFields().entrySet()) {
            Log.i("eve_response_header",header.getKey() + "=" + header.getValue());
        }
        //InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        this.exception = e;

        return null;
    }

    return "bla";
}

protected void onPostExecute(String... response) {
    // TODO: stuff
}


}
```

But the answer header is this:

```
10-23 18:54:43.613 29926-30158/com.jbs.evecompanion I/eve_response_header: null=[HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request]
10-23 18:54:43.613 29926-30158/com.jbs.evecompanion I/eve_response_header: Connection=[close]
10-23 18:54:43.613 29926-30158/com.jbs.evecompanion I/eve_response_header: Content-Length=[339]
10-23 18:54:43.614 29926-30158/com.jbs.evecompanion I/eve_response_header: Content-Type=[text/html; charset=us-ascii]
10-23 18:54:43.614 29926-30158/com.jbs.evecompanion I/eve_response_header: Date=[Sun, 23 Oct 2016 16:54:41 GMT]
10-23 18:54:43.614 29926-30158/com.jbs.evecompanion I/eve_response_header: Server=[Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0]
10-23 18:54:43.614 29926-30158/com.jbs.evecompanion I/eve_response_header: X-Android-Received-Millis=[1477241683613]
10-23 18:54:43.614 29926-30158/com.jbs.evecompanion I/eve_response_header: X-Android-Response-Source=[NETWORK 400]
10-23 18:54:43.614 29926-30158/com.jbs.evecompanion I/eve_response_header: X-Android-Selected-Protocol=[http/1.1]
10-23 18:54:43.614 29926-30158/com.jbs.evecompanion I/eve_response_header: X-Android-Sent-Millis=[1477241683576]
```

Which as you can see gives me a "Bad Request".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out the Base64 encoding did something weird.
Instead of Base64.DEFAULT I had to use Base64.NO_WRAP

so the line would be

```
String enc_auth = Base64.encodeToString("9d7dcbb0380f450ea0d2b435b60f4c15:ssEAFgv5PfEs29bluxs9N3milKgC7j6saILCtMPw".getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

Otherwise it would add random linebreaks in the encoded string.